# Creating a Java Application to authenticate with Active Directory using Single Sign ON

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on

I have struck at a problem. I'm completely new to java programming. I have to develop a java application and authenticate users using Active Directory. I am succesful in that part. But have to implement a Single Sign ON Application on top of it.Could you please guide me where to start. I followed many tutorials but haven't understood a word. please provide some straight links/tutorials. It will be very helpful if some tutorial code base is provided

Thanks in Advance.. !!!

Comment: Stackoverflow unfortunately isn't the place to solicit tutorial recommendations, or to ask broader how-to questions. Maybe try https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava

Comment: Atleast links/suggestions??

Comment: Re-read my comment. I gave you a link right there.